# Flux vs Night Shift?

Tags: display, macos, color

New MacOS sierra 10.12.4 introduced us new feature called **Night Shift** .

Is it better to stick with ***flux software*** https://justgetflux.com/ or just use ***Night Shift***?

Pros and cons of using these softwares for adapting display colours on late nights?

Edit:
There is interesting article about this on iMore site:
http://www.imore.com/night-shift-vs-flux-whats-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day (ho-ho!) it probably just comes down to which effect you prefer, as the science is [somewhat inconclusive](https://www.wired.com/2017/03/uncertain-science-behind-phones-blue-light-dimmer/) anyway. Night Shift's effect is more subtle even when turned all the way up, but it's rather less configurable than Flux.

The article you linked to basically already covers all this, and the relative merits of each:

Flux:

- Bigger variety of colour-shifting effects available
- More control over start/end time
- Can be permanently turned off for specific apps, e.g. video players or photo editors where you don't necessarily want colour-shifting to occur
- Can be temporarily turned off for all apps
- It's nice to support a 3rd-party developer

Night Shift:

- Better system integration; potentially easier on battery as a result (just a guess: I've not measured this, nor heard any anecdotal evidence either way)